# Perspective Distortion of Font CSS

Tags: html, css, transform, perspective

I am trying to achieve a perspective distortion of some text. I have looked into transform - perspective, masking etc. But I somehow don't seem to find the or even a way to do it.
It should look something like the text in quotes
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOqIN.png)

This is what I have so far:

```css
.blog-grid {
    display: grid; }
    .blog-grid a.single-blog {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 5fr 4fr;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      text-decoration: none; }
      .blog-grid a.single-blog:hover {
        cursor: pointer; }
      .blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-image {
        grid-column: 1 / span 1;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-color: lightblue;}
        .blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-image:before {
          padding-bottom: 100%;
          content: '';
          display: inline-block; }
      .blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-info {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 6fr 2fr;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;
        padding: 0 40px;
        color: #00329B; }
        .blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-info .blog-category {
          letter-spacing: 5px;
          font-size: 15px;
          text-align: center;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-weight: 600; }
        .blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-info .quote-box {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          transform: rotate(-3.5deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-3.5deg);
          -webkit-transform: rotate(-3.5deg);}
          .blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-info .quote-box .quote {
            font-size: 50px;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-style: italic;
            position: relative; }
```

```html
<div class="blog-grid">
  <a href="http://fabis-mac.local:5757/test-blog-drei/" class="single-blog" cat_id="3" style="height: 727px;">
    <div class="blog-image"></div>
    <div class="blog-info">
      <p class="blog-category">Menschen</p>
      <div class="quote-box"><span class="quote">Ich liebe mein Fahrrad mehr als meine Frau</span></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I hope my question is clear and I have provided enough info, otherwise I am open for feedback and ready to deliver more.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What specifically is lacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is use both the `skew` and `rotate` css transforms.

I also changed the font-family to sans-serif and removed the italic font-style while testing, so I could be more sure of the straight lines.

If you skew and rotate by the same amount, the effects should balance each other out for the straight lines you're going for.

```css
/* ---- This is the area to look at --- */
.blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-info .quote-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skew(-3.5deg) rotate(-3.5deg); 
  -ms-transform: skew(-3.5deg) rotate(-3.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-3.5deg) rotate(-3.5deg);
}
.blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-info .quote-box .quote {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* Copied from your post */
.blog-grid {
  display: grid;
}
.blog-grid a.single-blog {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 4fr;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.blog-grid a.single-blog:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-image {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-image:before {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
}
.blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 6fr 2fr;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 40px;
  color: #00329b;
}
.blog-grid a.single-blog .blog-info .blog-category {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-grid">
  <a href="http://fabis-mac.local:5757/test-blog-drei/" class="single-blog" cat_id="3" style="height: 727px;">
    <div class="blog-image"></div>
    <div class="blog-info">
      <p class="blog-category">Menschen</p>
      <div class="quote-box"><span class="quote">Ich liebe mein Fahrrad mehr als meine Frau</span></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help - exactly what I was looking for!
Almost a little ashamed of how easy it is...